# VS 2008 data package, stalling on "validating"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have one sequence container, with 4 other sequence containers inside.  When I execute it works fine, however if I try to add another sequence container to the five it stalls on a data flow in the new container, in the progress it's stuck on 33% validating, has anyone face issues like this before and have any suggestions?

Comment: I found that if the task before is a truncate and your validating the container you will get the stall, I switch to delete.

Comment: You could try setting Delay Validation to True for each component.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any fully cached lookup transforms? These can take an AGE to load the cache if the lookup tables are very large.